# jruby - import java class into jruby as different name

Tags: libgdx, jruby

I'm using a game framework, libgdx, which includes its own Array class which collides with the JRuby built-in Array. Is there a way to `java_import 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array'` with a different name? Something like

`java_import 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array', :as => GdxArray`

? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a solution!

First I tried this:

```
GdxArray = java_import 'com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array'
```

but that still resulted in the already initialized constant error. Second attempt:

```
# don't wallpaper over the JRuby Array class                                               
GdxArray = com::badlogic::gdx::utils::Array
```

A little funny looking with the lowercase package names, but it works!!